# Does this MakeRedemption.aspx is the parent page for the user control?

Tags: c#, user-controls, parent

I have a aspx page name MakeRedemption.aspx, the code is something as following :

```
<%@ Page Title="Make Redemption" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MakeRedemption.aspx.cs" Inherits="MakeRedemption" %>

<%@ Register Src="~/UserControls/MakeRedemption_SearchGift.ascx" TagName="MakeRedemption_SearchGift" TagPrefix="uc" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="bodyContent" Runat="Server">

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server"></asp:UpdatePanel>

<uc:MakeRedemption_SearchGift runat="server" ID="ucSearchGifts" GiftCategoryAvailable="false" /><% /*UnitCostAvailable="true"*/ %>

</asp:Content>
```

And I have a user control page name MakeRedemption_SearchGift.ascx.

I would like to ask, is the MakeRedemption.aspx consider a parent page for MakeRedemption_SearchGift.ascx ??
And MakeRedemption_SearchGift.ascx is the user control page of MakeRedemption.aspx

Kindly advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is. After do some research, testing, further with senior advice. It is.